# Nonstandard English Syntax

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What would be the best way to describe the non-standard syntax of "The spider he was confused."?

Comment: It's not really non-standard; just add a comma.

Comment: Apposition. The [RHK Webster's definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apposition). A more usual type is when a title is paralleled by a name: 'Mr Churchill, the Prime Minister, was watching a Marx Brothers farce': further information is concisely given.

Comment: The rule involved is called [_Left Dislocation_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf); it copies the subject to the beginning of the sentence, often with a comma, leaving behind a pronoun copy.